# Adding custom control to a Nette Form

Tags: nette, latte

I am attempting to add a custom control to a nette form, using the example given in the official documentation [here](https://github.com/nette/forms/blob/a0bc775b96b30780270bdec06396ca985168f11a/examples/custom-control.php).

I am having problems. First off I though I would try to use the example as a starting point. Unfortunately it doesn't work. when using the code provided I get

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in Composer\vendor\nette\utils\src\Utils\Html.php on line 494
Warning: Illegal offset type in Composer\vendor\nette\utils\src\Utils\Html.php on line 392
```

and only the label actually renders. Have I missed something obvious here or does the example just not work?

Comment: What version of Nette Forms, Nette Utils and PHP do you use? The examples code you linked is for a rather old version version of Nette (2.2).

Comment: PHP 7, and the Forms and Utils are the latest from Composer. I never noticed the date on those examples, They were linked off a post on the Nette forms from earlier this year so stupidly I thought they would be new.. I think I just need new examples.

Comment: You can try checking out later tags in the repo, e.g. https://github.com/nette/forms/blob/v3.1/examples/custom-control.php

Comment: Yep that is the problem 100%, someone linked to an old version and I didn't notice the date. Using the new version I am getting some joy with output, just need to work out how to nest things now.